# Future Recursion Patterns/Future Chaining of arbitrary length

Tags: scala, recursion, akka, future

I'm curious about the best way to recursively build a chain of Akka futures which will run sequentially, if a `doWork` call in a future fails, the future should be retried up to 3 times, the chain should fail if it runs out of retry attempts. Assuming all `doWork` calls pass the returned future `futChain` should only complete.

```
object Main extends App {
  val futChain = recurse(2)

  def recurse(param: Int, retries: Int = 3): Future[String] {
    Future {
      doWorkThatMayFailReturningString(param...)
    } recoverWith {
      case e => 
        if (retries > 0) recurse(param, retries -1)
        else  Future.failed(e)
    } flatMap {
      strRes => recurse(nextParam) //how should the res from the previous fut be passed?
    }
  }

  futChain onComplete {
    case res => println(res) //should print all the strings
  }
}
```

1. How can I get the results as a collection? i.e. in this example each `String` return from the `doWork` function (I need to somehow modify the `recurse` func to return a `Futrue[List[String]]`
2. Should I use `recover` or `recoverWith`?
3. Is it ok to call `flatMap` to chain these calls
4. Should I make considerations about tail recursion & stack overflows?
5. Would I be better to recursively build a list of futures and reduce them?

Comment: This question boils down to how to create arbitrarily long future chains using recursion. Not just plunking a bunch of pre defined futures in a for comprehension

Comment: `foldLeft` can be used to create dynamically sized chains of `Future`.

Comment: @RandallSchulz would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: Yes, but it'll have to wait ’til I get back to the office on Monday.

Answer (score 12):

You can implement a retryable `Future` like this:

```
def retry[T](f: => Future[T])(n: Int)(implicit e: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {
    n match {
        case i if (i > 1) => f.recoverWith{ case t: Throwable => retry(f)(n - 1)}
        case _ => f
    }       
}
```

This isn't optimized for tail recursion, but if you only intend on retrying a few times, you won't get a stack overflow (and I imagine if it's failed the first few, it's going to keep failing, anyway).

Then I would do the chaining separately. If you have a finite number of functions to chain together, each depending on the previous (and for some reason you want to aggregate the results) you can use `for` comprehensions (syntactic sugar for `flatMap`):

```
for {
    firstResult <- retry(Future(doWork(param)))(3)
    secondResult <- retry(Future(doWork(firstResult)))(3)
    thirdResult <- retry(Future(doWork(secondResult)))(3)
} yield List(firstResult, secondResult, thirdResult)
```

For an arbitrarily long chains, you can do them in parallel using `Future.sequence` (`Futures` in the Akka library):

```
def doWork(param: String): String = ...

val parameters: List[String] = List(...)

val results: Future[List[String]] = Future.sequence(parameters.map(doWork(_)))
```

This will unravel what would otherwise be `List[Future[String]]` to `Future[List[String]]`.

Here's one way to do a similar thing in sequence:

```
def sequential[A, B](seq: List[A])(f: A => Future[B])(implicit e: ExecutionContext): Future[List[B]] = {
    seq.foldLeft(Future.successful(List[B]())) { case (left, next) =>
        left.flatMap(list => f(next).map(_ :: list))
    }
}

def doWork(param: String): String = ...

val results: Future[List[String]] = sequential(parameters)(param => Future(doWork(param)))
```

The implementation of these functions is *very* sensitive to your use case. The two above functions will return failed futures if any of the futures in the chain failed. Sometimes you'll want this, other times not. If you want to collect only the successful futures, and discard failed ones without failing the entire result, you can add an extra step to recover the failures.

Additionally, the difference between `recover` and `recoverWith` is the type of `PartialFunction` it accepts. `recover` replaces failed futures with default values, while `recoverWith` does so using another `Future`. In the case of my `retry`, `recoverWith` is more appropriate because I'm trying to recover the failed `Future` with itself.

Comment: Yeah I understand the retry semantics. The question really is about how to implement arbitrary chains. Could you provide examples on how to implement arb chains. Using the for comprehension above isn't the same as recursion

Comment: @NightWolf You should make that more clear in your question. It would also be good to keep the retry and future chaining implementations separate.

Comment: Thanks for the update! This is a good approach, similar to this http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/execute-scala-futures-in-serial-one-after-the-other-non-blocking/ 
But the problem is this isn't really recursive as I need to define the parameter set at the beginning

Comment: Why does it need to be recursive? My last examples use a predefined parameter set, so I'm not really sure what you're looking for.