# Non blocking tail recursive

Tags: scala, recursion, future

I have a tail recursive implementation as below

```
@tailrec
def generate() : String = {
  val token = UUID.randomUUID().toString
  val isTokenExist = Await.result(get(token), 5.seconds).isDefined
  if(isTokenExist) generate()
  else token
}
```

`get(token)` will return a `Future[Option[Token]]`.

I know that blocking in a Future is not good. I tried to return a `Future[String]` instead of `String`. But seems that its not possible unless I wait for `isTokenExist` to be completed.

Any other way/suggestion to implement this?

Comment: Why does it have to be tail-recursive ? Why does `generate` have to return String and not Future[String] ? If you answer these questions, you can probably have a better API design. Not trying to flip your question, but this seems like an anti-pattern for Future usage and unnecessary usage of tail -recursion, IMO.

Comment: Its actually what I'm looking for, different implementation which returns a `Future[String]`. But, I cant seem to find a solution. I would be glad if you can shed some light :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generate does not have to be tail-recursive in this case since it uses Futures (read this: [How do I make a function involving futures tail recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973838/how-do-i-make-this-tail-recursive) for explanation).

Will this work for you ?

```
  def generate: Future[String] = {
    val token = UUID.randomUUID().toString
    get(token).flatMap {
      case None => generate
      case _    => Future.successful(token)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yeap, thanks for the help. Just thought about it as well that it doesn't need to be tail recursive (Holy sh.. im dumb). Appreciate the help :)

Comment: @Allan glad it works for you :) Also worth pointing at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308286/future-recursion-patterns-future-chaining-of-arbitrary-length in case you want to retry-able future construct.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening in `get(token)` such that if it exceeds 5s the first time, it won't also exceed it the second time?

If you really need to check (and collisions are **very** unlikely), you probably just need to block anyway. Otherwise, if 5s is not enough, the method will never return and you will get a Stackoverflow after a very long time.

I would probably just keep it simple:

```
def generate() : String = {
  val token = UUID.randomUUID().toString
  if(get(token).isDefined) generate()
  else token
}
```

If you need to optimize something in this code, it probably is the `get(token)` method.

Comment: HI Jean, I'm using slick 3 to make a call to the db to `get(token)`. Seems that (please do correct me If I'm wrong) the return type must be a `Future`. Do you think it would be okay, to block on the `get(token)` ?

Answer (score 0):

if you wrap `get(token)` in a future, then you can use future `onComplete` function. Something like:

```
val f: Future[Token] = Future {
  get(token)
}
f onComplete {
     case Success(token) => generate()
     case Failure(t) => println("An error has occured: " + t.getMessage)
}
```

for more info take a look at: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: `onComplete` returns `Unit`, you can't recurse in a useful way with it.